# How should I approach creating an iterable in a Django view that will allow me to group items by a foreign key (or lack thereof) in a template?

Tags: django

I have constructed a view that subclasses Django's ListView. Currently it works fine. It provides a list of objects from my Artwork class that I can iterate over in my template.

However, I've now included a (not required) foreign key (series) and I would like to group the Artwork objects by series when I display them. I would also like to order them by date while interspersing any Artwork objects with series=None amongst them (according to the date also).

Like this:

1. artwork(12/2013) **(series=None)**
2. artwork(12/2013) artwork(12/2013) artwork(11/2013) **(series='series1' 11/2013)**
3. artwork(10/2013) **(series=None)**
4. artwork(12/2013) artwork(12/2013) artwork(11/2013) **(series='series2' 09/2013)**

My models look like this:

```
class Series(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now(), editable=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Artwork(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    series = models.ForeignKey(Series, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now(), editable=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='artwork_images/%Y/%m/')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I'm guessing I could somehow accomplish what I want if my view were to provide the template with something like a nested list. Is this possible with the ListView? Or should I maybe be constructing a function based view?

Apologies if this seems like a naive question. I'm new to the Django/Python world (and Stackoverflow!). Any advice or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use a normal function based view for this, but if you want you can use `ListView`'s `get_context_data()` method to return arbitrary data.

1. Create a key function for sorting:

   ```
   def key_function(artwork):
       if artwork.series is None:
           return (artwork.date, None)
       else:
           return (artwork.series.date, artwork.series)
   ```

   The function uses serie's date if avialiable and artwork's date otherwise. Series id is a second part of the key (when available), so artworks belonging to the same series are kept next to each other, even if there are more than one serie with the same date.
2. Sort your data using the key:

   ```
   def your_view(request):
       artwork = Artwork.objects.select_related()
       artwork_list_sorted = sorted(artwork, key=key_function)
       return render(request, "your_app/artwork_list.html", {'artwork_list_sorted': artwork_list_sorted})
   ```

   or using `ListView`:

   ```
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(ArticleListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       queryset = self.get_queryset()
       context['artwork_list_sorted'] = sorted(queryset, key=key_function)
       return context
   ```
3. Use [the regroup template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) to group your data:

   ```
   {% regroup artwork_list_sorted by series as artwork_grouped %}

   {% for artwork in artwork_grouped %}
       {% for item in artwork.list %}
           {{ item.title }}({{ item.date }})
       {% endfor %}
       <strong>(series={{ artwork.grouper }})</strong>
   {% endfor %}
   ```

   or alternatively just iterate through the original sorted list, displaying series when needed - using the [ifchanged template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged):

   ```
   {% for artwork in artwork_list_sorted %}
       {{ artwork.title}}({{ artwork.date }})
       {% ifchanged %}<strong>(series={{ artwork.series.title }})</strong>{% endifchanged %}
   {% endfor %}
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did have to make a slight change to the template code - it needed a nested for loop to iterate over the list provided by 'regroup' and referring to the series was accomplished by artwork.grouper rather than artwork.series.title. Thanks again.

Comment: Right. Thank you. I was thinking about two possible solutions and then accidentally mixed them together. I edited my post, it now shows both of them, separately.